# MongoDB find $and with value of any

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

How can i use find with $and with some value all?

Example

```
let { city, zanr, date } = req.body;

const selectedEvent = await Events.find({
  $and: [{ address: city}, { type: zanr }, { date: datum }],
});
```

Because in req.body can be the value "all" thats mean i dont need sometimes filter.

Sometimes can be address: any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if city is all remove `{address:city}` from `and` array
or use `{address:{$regex:'.*.'}}`

```
 let { city, zanr, date } = req.body;

    const selectedEvent = await Events.find({
      $and: [ {address:{$regex:'.*.'}},{ type: zanr }, { date: datum }],
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but i have in front end three filter City [All, Berlin, New York] and if somebody will choose zanr [Concerts, Meeting] if somebody will chosee [Concerts] and city [All] what should i do?

Comment: i update my answer `{address:{$regex:'.*.'}}` means all address

Comment: Thanks allot ! This helped me make this more flexible :-))

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the query dynamically with javascript based on the `req.body`.
`MQL` queries are `JSON` we can generate them, change them etc.

For example

```js
var q;

if(city=="all") q=[{ type: zanr }, { date: datum }];
else q=[{ address: city}, { type: zanr }, { date: datum }];

const selectedEvent= await Events.find({$and: q});
```

You can do this for more optional filters if you have more than the city.